# Logstash filtering unstructured Logs

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I'm pretty new to Logstash and try my best to get a grip on it. My Problem is the following:
I have a Log which is structured like this:

time - data - message

every 10 to 15 log entrys are linked to one Job which has a ID but only the first entry of the job is marked with the ID.

I now want to try to add a field to every Entry that follows in order in identify all entrys related to a specific ID.

> Here an Example
>
> 29.09.15 16:17:00:191 - text text ID: 00000001 text text
>
> 29.09.15 16:17:00:206 - text text
>
> 29.09.15 16:17:00:253 - text text
>
> ...
>
> 29.09.15 16:17:26:539 - text text ID: 00000002 text text
>
> 29.09.15 16:17:30:233 - text text

I'm a bit lost. My current approach would be grok filtering to identify the ID but I'm clueless how to remember the ID and add it to the following entrys when I read them...

Answer (score 0):

I am too late for a resuce but if am not wrong, you should use multiline filter plugin of Logstash.

There you can mark the logline with ID as a start of an event. So whenever logstash finds a line with ID, it takes all the following lines and stash it as one full event till it finds another log line with ID again.

Read this below doc:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-multiline.html